# What happens when I enable associated domains for my iOS app ID?

Tags: ios, app-store, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am trying to enable universal links for my existing app. It seems I have to enable associated domains to do that. The dialog sounds pretty scary as I am still not very versed in these iOS certificate/provisioning profile concepts (even though I've been working on iOS apps for a quite a while I never get used to these).

One thing I'm concerned about is, if I press OK here, would it affect the existing app that's already being used by people? For example, I have push notification feature, I am not sure what would happen once I press OK here. I don't want push notification to stop functioning on my production app.

[image: Enable Associated Domains dialog]

Comment: Hey Vlad, have you tried it? I have to do the same for my app, so want to be sure it's safe for existing binary in Appstore.

Answer (score 1):

App ID changes

A provisioning profile attaining Invalid status due to App ID changes does not affect any currently deployed apps that were signed with that profile. It's just an indication that the profile must be regenerated/updated to reflect changes in services and entitlements made to its associated App ID before it can again be used for code signing.

Certificate expiration or revocation

For standard developer program teams (those whose distribution method is the iOS App Store), expiration or revocation of a code signing certificate does not affect any apps that were signed with that certificate (this includes development builds, beta test builds, and live App Store apps). Its just an indication that the profile must be regenerated/updated to be associated with a new, valid certificate.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1878/_index.html